# Not able to add view and path to a package

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls, django-apps

So I am trying for several days to make my own **function** on the package **"django-todo"**

I am able to add mine in the view, but when I tried and add to the path it does not work.

**I have register the app on my settings, I added the url to my main folder : `path('', include('todo.urls', namespace="apptodo")),`**

**Views.PY**

```
 @login_required
def add_list(request) -> HttpResponse:
    """Allow users to add a new todo list to the group they're in.
    """


    if request.POST:
        form = AddTaskListForm(request.user, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                newlist = form.save(commit=False)
                newlist.slug = slugify(newlist.name, allow_unicode=True)
                newlist.save()
                messages.success(request, "Une nouvelle catégorie a été ajoutée.")
                return redirect("todo:lists")

**And mine** 

    @login_required
def dailyadd_list(request) -> HttpResponse:
    """Allow users to add a new todo list to the group they're in.
    """


    if request.POST:
        form = AddTaskListForm(request.user, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                newlist = form.save(commit=False)
                newlist.slug = slugify(newlist.name, allow_unicode=True)
                newlist.save()
                messages.success(request, "Une nouvelle catégorie a été ajoutée.")
                return redirect("todo:lists")
```

Now on my **urls.py**

This one came with the package

```
path("add_list/", views.add_list, name="add_list"),
```

**Mine**

```
path("dailyadd_list/", views.dailyadd_list, name="add_list"),
```

It is weird, it's like there is setting that does not allow extra path...

Any idea ?

Comment: It's not clear what is the issue.

Comment: If I add my function to the url path it says "AttributeError: module 'todo.views' has no attribute 'dailyadd_list'"

Even though it is there

Answer (score 1):

In your **urls.py**, instead of:

```
path("dailyadd_list/", views.add_list, name="add_list")
```

Should be:

```
path("dailyadd_list/", views.dailyadd_list, name="add_list")
```

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. I actually wrote the correct way. It just doesn't want to find my view.

Comment: Looking at the package, you the add_list view is into add_list.py inside views module. So probably you need to import you function into views.py, like the add_list. Ex.:
from todo.views.add_list import add_list
from todo.views.add_list import dailyadd_list